# AnyChart Treemap drillChange current event out of sync with getDrilldownPath

Tags: listener, treemap, drilldown, anychart, anychart-8.2

With Anychart 8.3+ I am using the TreeMap `chart.listen('drillChange')` listener to obtain a clicked element's information.

Note: I needed to use `e.current.get('name')` as shown in [an example](https://playground.anychart.com/api/v8/_samples/anychart.enums.EventType.drillChange), instead of `e.currentTarget` as per Treemap [`listen()`](https://api.anychart.com/v8/anychart.charts.TreeMap#listen) documentation. However the `getDrillDownPath()` value seems to be one event-click behind. Why is this?

```
chart.listen("drillChange", function(e){
  // get the drilldown path and convert it to a string
  var text = printPath(chart.getDrilldownPath());

  // set the chart title
  chart.title().useHtml(true);
  chart.title("Treemap: Interactivity (Drillchange)" +
    "<br><br>currentTarget: " + e.currentTarget + 
    "<br><br>current.get('name'): " + e.current.get('name') + 
    "<br><br>Path: " + text
});
```

Below is a link to sample code, showing the undefined `e.currentTarget`, the defined `e.current.get('name')`, and the drilldown path value being one step behind.

https://playground.anychart.com/AeI6bUhK/7

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `e.currentTarget` is the default field which in some context can be undefined. The `getDrillDownPath()` function returns the path to the current level. The current level you can get from `e.current.get('name')`.
So, for your purpose the full path you can get like this:

```
  chart.title("Treemap: Interactivity (Drillchange)" +
    "<br><br>Path: " + text + "\\" + e.current.get('name')
  );
```

Comment: If I add the above line to my code, and click on the following: Item 1, Item 1-1, Item-1-1 header (to drill up to the Item 1 level), the Path displayed is: `Path: Root\Item 1\Item 1-1\\Item 1`, instead of the expected `Root\\Item 1`. [Sample code here](https://playground.anychart.com/oub56SQc/1) If I drill up to the root level, the path is now `Root\Item 1\\Root`