# how to implement drilldown in pie chart?

Tags: anychart

i have done drilldown on bar chart using your documentation which is provided at https://docs.anychart.com/Drilldown/Basics#create_a_chart

but now i want to display a pie chart and when i click on pie chart it gets drill down to bar chart and so on.

also i got to know about this but didnt understand well code in [AnyChart Treemap drillChange current event out of sync with getDrilldownPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54017423/anychart-treemap-drillchange-current-event-out-of-sync-with-getdrilldownpath) :-

chart.title("Treemap: Interactivity (Drillchange)" +
    "
Path: " + text + "\" + e.current.get('name')
  );

well i have only displayed basic of pie chart , now i want to drill down to bar chart if user clicks on it.

```
  <html>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>

<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:absolute; top:60px; left:10px; width:500px; height:500px;" id="container"></div>    
<script>

var data = [
  {x: "A", value: 637166 , "drillDown" :[
    {"x": "Q1", "value": 792026},
    {"x": "Q2", "value": 610501},
    {"x": "Q3", "value": 441843},
    {"x": "Q4", "value": 350711}
]},
  {x: "B", value: 721630},
  {x: "C", value: 148662},
  {x: "D", value: 78662},
  {x: "E", value: 90000}
];

// create a chart and set the data
chart = anychart.pie(data);

// set the container id
chart.container("container");

// initiate drawing the chart
chart.draw();
</script>
</body>
</html
```

>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach described in the Documentation, but it requires some modifications as you want to change chart type on drill-down. In this case, you should dispose the pie chart and create a bar chart and otherwise.
In the comment below you can check the sample which meets your requirements.
The approach with using `getDrilldownPath` is not compatible with Pie or Bar chart, because this API is specific for a Treemap chart which implements Tree-like data structure.

Comment: Here is a sample of a Pie chart with drill-down to Bar chart - https://playground.anychart.com/P7YpftV3/3